# Where can I find the formula to determine the PP capacity of a Psicrown?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, psionics

I am attempting to stat up a [psicrown](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psicrowns) with a custom list of stored powers, for a PF game using DSP's psionics rules. The Item Creation section in Ultimate Psionics covers how to calculate the cost of the new psicrown based on its manifester level and list of powers, but I have been unable to find the reference to how many PP it should hold at full charge.

There is a general formula in the books for PP in charged psionic items, which I had noticed as a pattern in the PP caps of the True psicrowns (thanks to Starwed for finding the reference for that rule), but it does not match with the printed values for the caps on the premade Lesser and Greater Psicrowns. Most of these seem to be at 1/3 and 2/3, respectively, of what the general rule calls for, but some are rather dramatically off. For example, Lesser Psicrown of Force and Fire and Greater Psicrown of Cautious Warrior both have ML 11, so using the 1/3 and 2/3 patterns, Lesser Psicrown of Force and Fire should have 36 2/3, rounded either to 36 or 37, while Greater Psicrown of Cautious Warrior should be 73 1/3. Instead, both are listed with a cap of 60 PP, which is too far off from either of those to be a rounding error, even rounding to the nearest 10. This apparent inconsistency is why I went looking for a more reliable, explicit statement on what they should have.

Cautious Warrior and Force and Fire have the same ML, but one is Lesser and one Greater, and both have the same 60 PP, which is 23 1/3 too high for one and 13 1/3 too low for the other, both too far off to be rounding to nearest 10.

The actual formula would be nice to have, also, but primarily what I'm looking for is the reference: a link to the SRD, a page number in the books, or preferably both.

Comment: I found the actual rules under [Creating Psicrowns](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/creating-psionic-items).  (For some reason I totally failed to find this in an initial search.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under [Creating Psicrowns](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/creating-psionic-items):

> Psicrowns are always created with full power points and have a maximum number of power points equal to **ten times the psicrown’s daily recharge rate.**

The recharge rates are determined by the type of psicrown:

> 1/3 psicrown’s manifester level (round down) for lesser, 1/2 psicrown’s manifester level (round up) for greater, and equal to psicrown’s manifester level for true.

The outlier you found is just an error: the psicrown of force and fire [should be a greater psicrown.](http://dreamscarredpress.com/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/p=37393.html#37393) (Apparently some but not all of the text had been updated, which leads to the contradiction you noticed.)

Comment: I did notice that the True ones given as examples all have 10*ML PP, but the ratio is not consistent for the other types. Most of the Lesser ones, for example, are capped at 10/3 of ML, but not all of them: Lesser Psicrown of Force and Fire, by that formula, should have 36 2/3 PP, but instead it has 60. That's more than a rounding error. Cautious Warrior and Force and Fire have the same ML, but one is Lesser and one Greater, and both have the same 60 PP, which is 23 1/3 too high for one and 13 1/3 too low for the other, both too far off to be rounding to nearest 10.

Comment: I'll edit the question to clarify this problem.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon I don't see Force and Fire on [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psicrowns).  (Everything on that page seems to follow the rule I suggest.) Maybe it's from a different source?

Comment: @MatthewNajmon There was an [error](http://dreamscarredpress.com/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/p=37393.html#37393) in the description of that psicrown.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for determining "daily recharge rate" are in the last paragraph of the [description of psicrowns](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psicrowns#TOC-Psicrown-Descriptions) before the list of "standard" varieties (emphasis mine):

> The minimum manifester level of a psicrown is 8th for lesser, 11th for greater, and 14th for true. The type of a specific psicrown determines its **daily recharge rate**: 1/3 psicrown’s manifester level (round down) for lesser, 1/2 psicrown’s manifester level (round up) for greater, and equal to psicrown’s manifester level for true.

The same paragraph appears in Dreamscarred Press' *Psionics Unleashed: Core Psionics System* on page 186.

However, this is not the maximum PP it can store! That's just how many it can be charged with per day by one manifester. The actual storage maximum is tucked away into the [item creation section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/creating-psionic-items#TOC-Creating-Psicrowns) of the rules (emphasis mine):

> Psicrowns are always created with full power points and have **a maximum number of power points equal to ten times the psicrown’s daily recharge rate**.

So a True psicrown, which has a minimum manifester level of 14, would have a daily recharge rate of 1 × ML = 14 PP, and a maximum capacity of 10 × daily recharge rate = 140 PP.

So if you're patient, you can super-charge a psicrown over the course of ten days and then go to town with it.